# Unable to find environment with name 'AzureCloud' Azure DevOps self-hosted Agent

Tags: azure, azure-devops

```
$servicePrincipalId = ""
$servicePrincipalKey = ''
$tenantId = ""
                   
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $servicePrincipalKey -AsPlainText -Force
$psCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($servicePrincipalId, $securePassword)
                   
Write-Verbose "Connect-AzAccount Started" -Verbose
$azureAccount = Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $tenantId -Credential $psCredential -Environment AzureCloud
```

Running this script with my self-hosted agent I get the error message in title. If I remove the '-Environment AzureCloud' it works just fine, however that environment is used in built-in tasks so I have to get that to work. I have tried to update my Az modules which did not help. How can I get the environment to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by removing the problematic earlier context files. Since the Azure DevOps agent run with 'NT Authority\Network Service' account the context is under '%systemroot%\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService.Azure'

I removed the whole '.Azure' directory, restarted all my powershell sessions and now have working agent.